# GROUP BY not working

Tags: php, sql, mysql, group-by

```
$sSql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT `tsu`.`id`) AS `count`
         FROM `" . $this->_sPrefix . "users` AS `tsu`
         INNER JOIN `" . $this->_sPrefix . "entries` AS `tse` 
             ON `tsu`.`id`=`tse`.`subscriber_id` 
                 AND `tse`.`subscriber_type`='" . BX_DOL_SBS_TYPE_VISITOR . "'
         WHERE 1
         GROUP BY `tsu`.`id`
         LIMIT 1";
```

Instead of counting the entries, it only returns 1.  If I remove the group BY clause then it works.  How can I fix the GROUP BY to make it work better?

Comment: what is it you are trying to get in your "COUNT"...how many subscribers for a particular user ID?

Comment: Matching id's from two different tables.

Comment: I'm no expert in mysql, but that "LIMIT 1" thing looks very suspicious to me.

Comment: $this->_sPrefix = "`; drop table [prefix]_users; --"; // Make sure you protect this DB no matter how you get it to work. I sure hope you generated $this->_sPrefix in your code, and that it doesn't have any user input in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE 1` does nothing, so it can be removed.

The `GROUP BY` can also be removed since you are not grouping by anything, your `COUNT DISTINCT` is on the whole table, no?

As Orbling points out, the `LIMIT 1` can be removed too because `COUNT DISTINCT` returns only one value by definition.

Does it do what you want then?

Answer (score 1):

You are grouping by `tsu`.`id`.

Each individual `tsu`.`id` group will by definition only have 1 distinct `tsu`.`id` in the group what do you expect it to return?

Comment: the actual count of entries: 23

Comment: Aye, the `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and the `LIMIT` can go.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.id, COUNT(e.id)
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN entries AS e ON e.subscriber_id = u.id
WHERE e.subscriber_type = 'BX_DOL_SBS_TYPE_VISITOR'
GROUP BY u.id
```